# Can the plural form of "sheep" ever be "sheeps"?

Tags: grammatical-number

A friend studies "(technical term) fish**es**" that is, he studies a group of similar fish species that all share this specific trait. Similarly you might study the native people**s** of X, i.e. the plural of the set of tribes/groups.

Can you do this with any plural noun? Has anyone ever studied sheeps/sheepes—the group of different breeds of sheep ?

Comment: I have never read/heard "sheeps" (from a literate source, that is). I'd be wary of trying to use that construction, unless you find significant precedent.

Comment: FWIW, I think you can, but I can't back that up with a citation.

Comment: Shakespeare used *sheeps* in the *Love's Labour's Lost*: "Two hot sheeps, marry."

Comment: @ermanen - but given that he couldn't spell his own name I'm not sure we can entirely trust Bill !

Answer (score 4):

I found this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-word-sheeps-a-grammatically-correct-form-for-the-plural-of-the-collective-noun-Sheep) which asked the same thing.
The users over there agree that no, *sheeps* is not a word in English, even though you may have sentences like "the peoples of the world."

From [the article about the plural of fish](http://grammarist.com/usage/fish-fishes/) on Grammarist.com

> The plural of fish is usually fish, but fishes has a few uses. In biology, for instance, fishes is used to refer to multiple species of fish.

As you can see, "fishes" is only acceptable in biology, and we can assume it is used as a technical term, rather than simply the plural of fish.
As pointed out in a comment below, fish is in fact an exception, and uncountable nouns (e.g. sheep, elk) cannot have a plural.

I hope I helped you a bit.

Comment: Most mass nouns can form a plural in this way, to mean "types of _whatever_", or "specific instances of _whatever_": waters, kindnesses, beauties. But count nouns that have the same form in the plural (eg _sheep_, _deer_) usually cannot do this - _fish_ is an exception.

Comment: @Colin Fine I second this. Three fishes in the tank, three quails in the bag. Not sheep.

Comment: @ColinFine: Really? Can you cite a reference for that? I don't think so. I think it's rather a general rule that applies to *sheeps* as kinds of sheep just as much as it applies to *deers* as species of the deer family (moose and elk are deers), *trouts* as kinds of trout (e.g., salmons are trouts, meaning all species of salmons are in the trout family), etc. But I don't have a citation to support my feeling either.

Comment: I haven't a citation, except the negative one that the OED has no example of plural _sheeps_ since 1658, and of _deers_ since 1817; and neither of those examples were in the sense of "kinds of sheep/deer". (It gives dialect _ships_ up to 1890, but still in the ordinary sense of several animals).

Comment: 'Sheep' is not an uncountable noun—it is just that the singular form is the same as the plural form. You wouldn't say 'there is much sheep over there', would you?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586484/2085).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't apply the same rules for plurals to just any word. There are a number of ways that plurals are derived, and some exceptions as in the "fishes" example you presented; in the case of sheep the plural will always be sheep.

For more information on the formation of plurals have a look at [this article on the OED blog titled "The Formation of Plurals, from sheep to minotaurs".](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/01/formation-plurals-minotaurs/)

Comment: The cited page does not deal with *sheeps* as breeds of sheep, a la *fishes* vs *fish*. It doesn't speak to that at all. It deals only with the plural of sheep individuals, not a collection of kinds of sheep.